# Simulate a multiple file upload with one file

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient

Hi to all I have a sample code using Jakarta HttpClient that uploads a file to a web server.
What i want is to simulate a multiple file upload of the same file with different name for each upload. 
Is this possible? Any hints?

A.K.

Comment: Needs more details.  What's stopping you from doing it right now?

Comment: Well i upload the file in multiple threads. What i want is to upload in each thread for testing the same file but with different filename!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add different multipart parts with same file content but a different part and filename. With [`InputStreamBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/InputStreamBody.html) you can specify a different filename for each part. E.g.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("file1", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), "name1.ext"));
entity.addPart("file2", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), "name2.ext"));
entity.addPart("file3", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), "name3.ext"));
// ...
```

In the Servlet code, assuming that you're using [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload), you could just iterate over the multipart items which you've extracted from the request with help of the FileUpload API in a for loop.

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        // Process regular field.
    } else {
        // Process uploaded file.
    }
}
```

Comment: How the InputStreamBody can be written in HttpClient 3.x?

Comment: I see that you already asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926391/inputstreambody-equivalent-in-httpclient-3-x) about that :)

Comment: Yes. Your answer is perfectly right, but with HttpClient 3 i can't make it work!

Comment: @system: uh, in the above example? There are 3 parts.

Comment: @BalusC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499954/app-engine-and-commons-fileupload

Comment: @system: not related to basic HttpClient API. It's likely Android specific.