# InputStreamBody equivalent in HttpClient 3.x

Tags: java, httpclient

In a previous question of mine I got the following answer, which is perfect,
but if I want to write my client with HttpClient 3.x, what is the equivalent code?
Especially "InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file)"?

> Just add different multipart parts with same file content but a different part and filename. With InputStreamBody you can specify a different filename for each part. E.g.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("file1", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), "name1.ext"));
entity.addPart("file2", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), "name2.ext"));
entity.addPart("file3", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), "name3.ext"));
// ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent class is `org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity`